# :nth-child() not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to stretch an image on the background for print for the third th with the :nth-child(5); but it does not catch it. Am I doing something wrong?

```css
table#OppPracticeOverview tr th {
    padding:5px !important;
    background-color:transparent;
}
table#OppPracticeOverview tr th img {
    width:47px;
    height:22px;
    float:left;
    margin:-5px 0 0 -42px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}
table#OppPracticeOverview tr th img:nth-child(5) {
    width:110px;
    height:22px;
    float:left;
    margin:-5px 0 0 -105px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="OppPracticeOverview">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Patients
            <img src="/images/img-CCCCCC.png">
       </th>
       <td>
       <th>
           On Hold
           <img src="/images/img-CCCCCC.png">
        </th>
        <td>
        <th>
           Reattribution Request
          <img src="/images/img-CCCCCC.png">
       </th>
       <td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: why do you have a td wrapped around a th and also unclosed? look at the strcuture here  - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp, could be part of the problem.

Comment: Combination of improper HTML syntax and an incorrect number in nth-child is your problem.

Comment: @blachawk: Actually I don't think the td is wrapping the th. There is no closing td tag at all.

Comment: @Michael: I looked at the markup again and just noticed the lone `<td>` tags which, while unconventional or at least inconsistent with the closing `</th>` tags, are not invalid syntax at all. `:nth-child(5)` should therefore match the third th because it's the fifth child of the tr; it's just applying to the wrong element in the selector so it isn't a problem in the markup.

Answer (score 3):

You were almost right, just move the `nth-child` from `img` to `th` like this: `table#OppPracticeOverview tr th:nth-child(5) img`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G79X9/1/

Answer (score 1):

It's nth-child relative to it's parent. So you're saying "the 5th `img` its parent the `th`". Your html is screwy (as in wrong), but I think you should try targeting the `th` instead.

Comment: To be more precise, it's "the 5th `img` in its parent, occurring within a `th`". The `th` may or may not be its parent. The HTML doesn't seem wrong to me, but the closing tags aren't consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't work because none of your `th` have 5 images. I think you want

```css
table#OppPracticeOverview tr th:nth-child(5) img {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I made a small mistake

```
.someclassA .someclassB: nth-child(odd){
```

You can see as above there is one space between someclassB:   and  nth-child.  thats it..
By deleting that space it started working :)

Answer (score 0):

**Some time nth-child not work try this nth-of-type()**

```
table#OppPracticeOverview tr th:nth-of-type(5) img
```

this is working for me